# Flutter Local Notification not showing Icon at Status Bar

Tags: dart, flutter, localnotification

I've integrated flutter ocal notification and everything is perfect but when the notification shows, no Icon is shown at the Status Bar.

Does this require additional steps? How do i go about it?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the icon didn't show at Status bar for Ongoing notification `ongoing: true`